# Calculate amount with condition

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

i want to do sum calculation for Amount if the type same as condition

here is my expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!transactionType.Value.Equals("BUY"),CDec(Fields!Amount.Value),0))
```

`Fields!Amount.Value` in database is decimal

but it show me #ERROR on display in rdlc report

Answer (score 0):

=SUM(CDec(IIF(Fields!transactionType.Value.Equals("BUY"),Fields!Amount.Value,0)))

because IIF(Fields!transactionType.Value.Equals("BUY"),CDec(Fields!Amount.Value),0) return object